# Few CSS selectors doesnot work in safari browsers like min-width, how do popular websites handle these type of problems

Tags: reactjs

Few CSS selectors doesnot work in safari browsers like min-width, how do popular websites handle these type of problems releated to broweser dependent issue. do they conditionally use for browsers like if(safari ) do these else do nothing ?

i have tried using conditionally by the browser type.but want to know how large webpage work on this.since, not everytime we can handle through the conditon for every css selectors for browser type

Comment: what does this have to do with [tag:reactjs]?

Comment: show us your code how you are using min-width as a selector.

Comment: min-width should work in Safari https://caniuse.com/?search=min-width

Comment: But can someone tell how browser depeency issues are handled in large companies . do they use like safar? use safari height : use chrome height like that